# Pass extra parameters to usort callback

Tags: php, wordpress, callback, usort

I have the following functions. WordPress functions, but this is really a PHP question. They sort my `$term` objects according to the `artist_lastname` property in each object's metadata.

I want to pass a string into `$meta` in the first function. This would let me reuse this code as I could apply it to various metadata properties.

But I don't understand how I can pass *extra* parameters to the usort callback. I tried to make a JS style anonymous function but the PHP version on the server is too old (v. 5.2.17) and threw a syntax error.

Any help - or a shove towards the right corner of the manual - gratefully appreciated. Thanks!

```
function sort_by_term_meta($terms, $meta) 
{
  usort($terms,"term_meta_cmp");
}

function term_meta_cmp( $a, $b ) 
{
    $name_a = get_term_meta($a->term_id, 'artist_lastname', true);
    $name_b = get_term_meta($b->term_id, 'artist_lastname', true);
    return strcmp($name_a, $name_b); 
}
```

PHP Version: 5.2.17

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In PHP, one option for a [callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) is to pass a two-element array containing an object handle and a method name to call on the object. For example, if `$obj` was an instance of class `MyCallable`, and you want to call the `method1` method of `MyCallable` on `$obj`, then you can pass `array($obj, "method1")` as a callback.

One solution using this supported callback type is to define a single-use class that essentially acts like a closure type:

```
function sort_by_term_meta( $terms, $meta ) 
{
    usort($terms, array(new TermMetaCmpClosure($meta), "call"));
}

function term_meta_cmp( $a, $b, $meta )
{
    $name_a = get_term_meta($a->term_id, $meta, true);
    $name_b = get_term_meta($b->term_id, $meta, true);
    return strcmp($name_a, $name_b); 
} 

class TermMetaCmpClosure
{
    private $meta;

    function __construct( $meta ) {
        $this->meta = $meta;
    }

    function call( $a, $b ) {
        return term_meta_cmp($a, $b, $this->meta);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this, but I think I like @Kato's better as it's sort of 'chunked out' into a little machine - are there advantages to instantiating a new object each time?

Comment: @djb: Kato's solution essentially introduces a global variable where the `$meta` string is held. PHP is single-threaded, so this is not a deal-breaker. However, I think that it is cleaner to encapsulate the `$meta` string so that code cannot accidentally change the static variable's contents while a sort is being performed.

Comment: ah, now I understand why. I can see its conceptual cleanliness... accepted. thanks.

Comment: @Daniel - I agree about encapsulation and hadn't considered passing an actual object as the first arg instead of the class name; great solution! That said, I think that the static approach is a bit easier to grok and follow mentally, as noted by djb's initial comments; trade-offs trade-offs ;)

Answer (score 111):

I think this question deserves an update. I know the original question was for PHP version 5.2, but I came here looking for a solution and found one for newer versions of PHP and thought this might be useful for other people as well.

For PHP 5.3 and up, you can use the '*use*' keyword to introduce local variables into the local scope of an anonymous function. So the following should work:

```php
function sort_by_term_meta(&$terms, $meta) {
    usort($terms, function($a, $b) use ($meta) {
        $name_a = get_term_meta($a->term_id, 'artist_lastname', true);
        $name_b = get_term_meta($b->term_id, 'artist_lastname', true);
        return strcmp($name_a, $name_b);  
    });
}
```

### Some more general code

If you want to sort an array just once and need an extra argument you can use an anonymous function like this:

```php
usort($arrayToSort, function($a, $b) use ($myExtraArgument) {
    //$myExtraArgument is available in this scope
    //perform sorting, return -1, 0, 1
    return strcmp($a, $b);
});
```

If you need a reusable function to sort an array which needs an extra argument, you can always wrap the anonymous function, like for the original question:

```php
function mySortFunction(&$arrayToSort, $myExtraArgument1, $myExtraArgument2) {
    usort($arrayToSort, function($a, $b) use ($myExtraArgument1, $myExtraArgument2) {
        //$myExtraArgument1 and 2 are available in this scope
        //perform sorting, return -1, 0, 1
        return strcmp($a, $b);
    });
}
```

Comment: Great! May I suggest to modify your first example to actually use the $meta parameter, so that it would be clearer.

Comment: Super useful, thanks; realized you can also pass in multiple arguments that way `($extraArgument1, $extraArgument2)`

Comment: How would you go about defining the compare function not as a closure but separately (so you can reuse it).

Comment: `usort($terms, function($a, $b) use ($meta) {`  - of course, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you've access to objects and static (PHP 5 or greater), you can create an object and pass the arguments directly there, like so:

```
<?php
class SortWithMeta {
    private static $meta;

    static function sort(&$terms, $meta) {
       self::$meta = $meta;
       usort($terms, array("SortWithMeta", "cmp_method"));
    }

    static function cmp_method($a, $b) {
       $meta = self::$meta; //access meta data
       // do comparison here
    }

}

// then call it
SortWithMeta::sort($terms, array('hello'));
```

Assuming you don't have access to objects/static; you could just do a global:

```
$meta = array('hello'); //define meta in global

function term_meta_cmp($a, $b) {
   global $meta; //access meta data
   // do comparison here
}

usort($terms, 'term_meta_cmp');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. I think I prefer this to creating a new object each time? Or is @Daniel's method cleaner?

Comment: In static method `SortWithMeta::sort`, I believe that parameter `$terms` needs to be passed by reference.

Comment: @Daniel - yes, I think it needs to be passed by reference; updating now

Comment: @djb - Daniel's is technically going to use less resources because $meta can get garbage collected (you could always add `self::$meta = null;` inside cmp_method() to make them equivalent!), but it's not going to be significant unless $meta contains massive data; go with what is easiest to grok and manipulate for you; I like both ;)

Answer (score 3):

> **Warning**
>   This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.

The docs say that [`create_function()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) should work on PHP >= 4.0.1. Does this work?

```
function term_meta_cmp( $a, $b, $meta )  {
    echo "$a, $b, $meta<hr>"; // Debugging output
}
$terms = array("d","c","b","a");
usort($terms, create_function('$a, $b', 'return term_meta_cmp($a, $b, "some-meta");'));
```

Comment: Well, this does work, but doesn't really solve the problem. You are still passing the meta hardcoded into the comparison function, a variable is whats's needed.

Comment: Great ! this is the only way I found to call a recursive closure without messing up with an index parameter ! Sadly this function is deprecated in PHP 7.2 and should be replaced by a native anonymous function (closure) as it uses `eval()` which *is evil*

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you at all with `usort()` but might be helpful nevertheless.  You could sort the array using one of the other sorting functions, [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/array_multisort).

The idea is to build an array of the values that you would be sorting on (the return values from `get_term_meta()`) and multisort that against your main `$terms` array.

```
function sort_by_term_meta(&$terms, $meta) 
{
    $sort_on = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $sort_on[] = get_term_meta($term->term_id, $meta, true);
    }
    array_multisort($sort_on, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $terms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What is the Simplest Solution to Passing Args to usort()?

I like many of the answers here, but I wanted to have a solution that could be done as simply as possible, *but could also be demonstrated!*  When calling `usort`, supply extra arguments like this...

```
usort($sortable, [$arg1, $arg2, ... $argn, compareFunction]);
```

But make sure to define these arguments before, so, you'll end up with something like...

```
$arg1 = 'something';
$arg2 = 'something else';
$argn = 'yet another thing';

usort($sortable, [$arg1, $arg2, ... $argn, compareFunction]);
```

Then `$arg1`, `$arg2`, and `$argn` will be available to the `compareFunction()`.

#### Demo It Up!

To demonstrate, here is a `usort()` that only considers the first three letters of elements being compared...

```
function cmp ($a, $b) {
     return strcmp(substr($a, 0, $num), substr($a, 0, $num));
}

$terms = ['123a', '123z', '123b',];
$num = 3;
$thing = 4;
usort($terms, [$num, $thing, cmp]);

print_r($terms);
```

[**Full Working Demo Online**](https://ideone.com/SavLaN)