# Sort php sub array based on sub key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, nest

Here is a snippet of my array that is used in php 5.3.x :

```
$arr[$category][$item][$attr_qty] = 3;
$arr[$category][$item][$attr_price] = 12.00;
```

`$category` are arbitrary integers, as are `$item`, as are `$attr_qty` and `$attr_price`.

Is there a quick way of sorting, by `$attr_qty`, the items in each category?

Using integers makes the code easier, but I get the feeling I will have to use associative arrays.

Comment: using an associative array + something like [Sort PHP multi-dimensional array based on key?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16306693/1700963) might work for what you need?

Comment: Found the solution and it is called a wrapped reusable function with extra arguments - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230538/pass-extra-parameters-to-usort-callback function - function fsort_subarray( &$arr, $index, $dir )
{
  usort( &$arr, function( $a, $b ) use ( $index, $dir )
    {
      if((int)$dir == 0)
      {
       return ( $a[$index] >  $b[$index]);
      }
      else
      {
        return ( $a[$index] <  $b[$index]);
      }
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which allows you to specify a custom sorting function

```
usort($arr, 'customSortFunction');

function customSortFunction($a, $b)
{
    if     ($a['item']['attr_qty'] > $b['item']['attr_qty']) return 1;  //First element is bigger
    elseif ($a['item']['attr_qty'] < $b['item']['attr_qty']) return -1; //Second element is bigger
    else return 0;  //Both are equal
}
```

Comment: OP's array indexes are integer based not associative.