# How to pass usort() a parameter?

Tags: php, sorting, usort

My code:

```
function sortx($a, $b) {
    if(!strpos($a["p_title"],'apple ipad')) {
        return -1; 
    }
    return 1;
}
usort($arr, 'sortx');`
```

In above function I want to pass:
`$sort_text='apple ipad';`
, when calling function instead of hardcoding `apple ipad` into `strpos()`. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Note: you are paobably using `!strpos(...)` incorrectly. This evaluates to true if string does not contain "apple ipad" or begins with "apple ipad"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass extra parameters to usort callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230538/pass-extra-parameters-to-usort-callback)

Comment: @Rizier123, this is not duplicate, because here I want to pass whole function inside usort() function, please remove it from duplicate category.

Comment: @MujahedAKAS Where did I say that this is a dupe?

Comment: sorry Rizier123 it was @kewin Brown, Salman A, I will use `strpos($a["p_title"],'apple ipad') !== false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it with a closure:

```
$sort_text='apple ipad';
usort(
    $arr, 
    function ($a, $b) use ($sort_text) {
        if(!strpos($a["p_title"], $sort_text)) {
            return -1; 
        }
        return 1;
    }
);
```

and you can pass additional arguments with the `use` clause

Comment: My bad.... remove the function name.... it's using an anonymous function, so it doesn't have a name... that'll teach me to cut/paste from the question.... answer edited accordingly