# Can I pass additional parameters into an inline usort function?

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```
$external_variable = TRUE;
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    // do sorting stuff based on $external_variable
});
```

How can I access and use $external_variable within the usort function?

Comment: `$GLOBALS['external_variable']` ... but... ugh, avoid using globals.

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite consider that a solution, haha. I'm gathering it may not be possible?

Comment: It's entirely possible, @CGriffin. See my answer.

Comment: Here is an over the top way to do it lol: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230538/pass-extra-parameters-to-usort-callback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `use` keyword:

```
$external_variable = TRUE;

usort($array, function($a, $b) use($external_variable) {
    // do sorting stuff based on $external_variable
});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct. From PHP 7.1, these variables must not include superglobals, `$this`, or variables with the same name as a parameter.

Comment: D'oh, I tried that but forgot to put the variable in parentheses like an idiot. Thanks!