# PHP Sorting array with usort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array `$list` that I'm trying to sort. I'm using a function that does that like so:

```
function sortNodes($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->$title, $b->$title);
}
usort($list, 'sortNodes');
```

but I need to pass an extra parameter to that function. Something like:

```
function sortNodes($a, $b, $node) {
   return strcmp($a->$node, $b->$node);
}
usort($list, 'sortNodes');
```

The `$node` parameter needs be fetch from URL with `$_GET` but this way it isn't functioning.
How can i do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230538/pass-extra-parameters-to-usort-callback

Comment: post you input array and expected sorted output array

Comment: One way of providing extra information to a closure is to pass it via a _use_ clause? e.g. `function sortNodes($a, $b) use ($node) { `...

Comment: @RyanVincent, tks =) with your comment i've manage to make it work =)