# How do you pass a variable into a non-inline function used by usort?

Tags: php, sorting

usort allows custom inline functions and variables to be used with them:

eg

```
    usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    });
```

usort also allows the sort functions to be defined separately

eg

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($arr, 'cmp');
```

I have a large comparison function that I want to define separately and not as an inline function.
How do I pass a variable to usort and cmp?

Comment: How about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230538/pass-extra-parameters-to-usort-callback. You'll basically create your own sort function that will execute usort and be responsible for passing variables to it as needed

Comment: Please share more details. Anything not working with `use`?

Comment: @NicoHaase When I try:
```
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    // TODO: special handling for $c

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);

$c = "c";
// Sort and print the resulting array
usort($array, 'cmp') use $c;
print_r($array);
```

I get:PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "use" in usort_cmp.php on line 17

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "use" in usort_cmp.php on line 17

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, `use` is aprt of the function definition, not of the function call

Answer (score 2):

`usort` second argument expects a `callable` - Any argument that can be called will be executed with the two arguments.

```php
// Function:
$cmp = function($a, $b) { return $a <=> $b; }
usort($arr, $cmp);
```

```php
// Arrow Function:
$cmp = fn($a, $b) => $a<=>$b;
usort($arr, $cmp);
```

```php
// Class member:
class Tools {
    static function cmp($a, $b)
    {
        return $a <=> $b;
    }
}
usort($arr, [Tools::class, "cmp"]);
```

And so on....

For extra arguments, you can use the `use` keyword as part of the function declaration.

I suggest wrapping the `usort` procedure you want. This makes the code cleaner and more manageable:

```php
function my_sort(array &$arr, bool $space = true) {
    usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($space) {
       return $space ? $a <=> $b : $a < $b;
    });
} 
my_sort($arr, false);
```

Or with an Arrow function:

```php
function my_sort(array &$arr, bool $space = true) {
    usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => $space ? $a <=> $b : $a < $b);
} 
my_sort($arr, false);
```